# count no of words in each paragraph in a single file.. based upon map

Tags: java, mapreduce

Actually this is mapreduce program. This is my simple wordcount program:

```
 public static class MapClass extends MapReduceBase
    implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
                    OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output,
                    Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
      String line = value.toString();
      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(line);
      while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(itr.nextToken());
        output.collect(word, one);
```

Here I count the number of words in a file. 
                                              
 But i need to get no of words in each paragraph in a file.. we get numerical value for each paragraph. Now map based upon that no.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding what paragraph a particular line is in is not really possible within a single mapper.  You need to put some of that logic somewhere  else.

One approach would be to write a new InputFormat that passes not lines but entire paragraphs at a time to the mapper.  Right now the mapper is passed both the text for a line and the line number.  This other approach would pass in the entire paragraph and the paragraph number.

A less scalable approach would be to create a mapping between line number and paragraph number.  In your word count mapper you could write out the word, the count and the line the word is on.  Then you could join those records with the line to paragraph mapping to produce a count of words in each paragraph.